# RuntimeException: Unable to scan input when loading a page in AEM

Tags: aem, sling

One of the most commonly used pages in our AEM application stopped working today and every time it's requested, the following (or very similar) entry appears in the error log:

```
*ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1460623324684] GET /content/floccinaucinihilipilification/foo/bar.html HTTP/1.1] 
com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter Error during include of SlingRequestPathInfo: 
path='/content/floccinaucinihilipilification/foo/bar/jcr:content/par/jabberwocky', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to scan input
    at com.adobe.granite.xss.impl.HtmlToHtmlContentContext.filter(HtmlToHtmlContentContext.java:72)
    at com.adobe.granite.xss.impl.XSSFilterImpl.filter(XSSFilterImpl.java:194)
    at com.adobe.granite.xss.impl.XSSFilterImpl.filter(XSSFilterImpl.java:182)
    at com.adobe.granite.xss.impl.XSSAPIImpl.filterHTML(XSSAPIImpl.java:270)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.writeEpilog(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:198)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:431)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.IncludeTagHandler.dispatch(IncludeTagHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.doEndTag(AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.parsys.parsys_jsp._jspService(parsys_jsp.java:318)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:524)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:150)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:431)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMScriptHelper.includeResource(WCMScriptHelper.java:138)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMScriptHelper.includeResource(WCMScriptHelper.java:86)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.internal.extensions.ResourceExtension.call(ResourceExtension.java:99)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderContextImpl.call(RenderContextImpl.java:89)
    at apps.floccinaucinihilipilification.core.commons.renderers.someRenderer.SightlyJava_bodyContent.render(SightlyJava_bodyContent.java:39)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderUnit.render(RenderUnit.java:52)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.evaluateScript(SightlyScriptEngine.java:95)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.eval(SightlyScriptEngine.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMScriptHelper.includeScript(WCMScriptHelper.java:181)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.internal.extensions.IncludeExtension.call(IncludeExtension.java:70)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderContextImpl.call(RenderContextImpl.java:89)
    at apps.floccinaucinihilipilification.core.commons.renderers.pageRenderer.SightlyJava_body.render(SightlyJava_body.java:147)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderUnit.render(RenderUnit.java:52)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.evaluateScript(SightlyScriptEngine.java:95)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.eval(SightlyScriptEngine.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMScriptHelper.includeScript(WCMScriptHelper.java:181)
    at com.adobe.cq.sightly.internal.extensions.IncludeExtension.call(IncludeExtension.java:70)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderContextImpl.call(RenderContextImpl.java:89)
    at apps.floccinaucinihilipilification.core.commons.renderers.pageRenderer.SightlyJava_pageRenderer.render(SightlyJava_pageRenderer.java:50)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderUnit.render(RenderUnit.java:52)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.evaluateScript(SightlyScriptEngine.java:95)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.SightlyScriptEngine.eval(SightlyScriptEngine.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:150)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:252)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:431)
    at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:524)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:121)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:205)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:298)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This looks like a problem with the evaluation of the Sightly scripts rendering the page with little to no references to our custom back-end code (beyond the compiled Sightly templates)

I've checked [this thread about a similar `Unable to scan input` exception on the Adobe help forums](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__jdsx-after_a_batchimport.html) but this doesn't seem to be the case.

The length of this page is way below the limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that there were simply too many components placed on this particular page.

Further investigation of the logs revealed a number of `org.apache.sling.api.request.TooManyCallsException` instances.

This happens when Sling performs too many internal calls when serving a single request. The limit is configurable in the *Apache Sling Main Servlet* configuration in the OSGi console (`/system/console/configMgr`)

The setting is called *Number of Calls per Request*

In our case, it was set to 1500 calls and the page just happened to contain slightly above 1500 components when the error was reported. We decided to re-design the whole page and replace it with something more sustainable. The limit was raised higher as a quick workaround to give us time to come up with the proper solution.

I also learned that this problem may surface in existing pages when migrating to AEM 6.2 (in Beta as of the time of writing of this post) where the default OOTB configuration of the limit has been changed from 1500 to 1000 internal calls.